# unable to restart networking daemon

Tags: networking, daemon, start-stop-daemon

When I type `sudo service networking restart`, I am getting error as shown below:

```
edward@computer:~$ sudo service networking restart
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
```

Got this error when I wanted to restart `networking` after changing mac address and also after setting static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

I get same error even after reverting back those changes and when my computer works fine.

While looking through `/var/log/syslog` I found this:

```
kernel: [ 6448.036144] init: networking post-stop process (28701) 
                                                  terminated with status 100
```

is that relevant to the failed stop/start?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - did you reboot after making that MAC change? Ubuntu/Debian logs, `/var/log/syslog` or in `dmesg`.

Comment: @slm here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mlE-ZCN6aWQUVtXzdKOVMwbG8/view?usp=sharing) to my `syslog` file

Comment: @slm here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8mlE-ZCN6aWbnBWNlQ4WGNvMDQ/view?usp=sharing) to my `dmesg` file

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I cleaned up my comments, the relevant result is now in the question. Maybe you can do the same for those that don't really help future readers of this Q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error (`post-stop`) in your log seems related to this (in `/etc/init/networking.conf` line 25ff.):

```
post-stop script
    if [ -z "$UPSTART_STOP_EVENTS" ]; then
        echo "Stopping or restarting the networking job is not supported."
        echo "Use ifdown & ifup to reconfigure desired interface."
        exit 100
    fi
```

You get the exit code, but not the more informative message if you do `sudo service networking restart`.

There is a lot of detail in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015) about the issue. It seems deprecated behaviour. `/etc/init.d/networking stop` doesn't work any more and on Debian Jessie `sudo service networking stop` doesn't have any effect either. You seem to have to run `ifup`/`ifdown` on the individual network interfaces now, so let's hope you don't have too many of them.

If using `ifup`/`ifdown` is unacceptable, [this](https://github.com/metral/restore_networking) allows you to restore the 13.10 behaviour.

**The final solution for it is: `sudo service network-manager restart`**

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I hope you get the MAC / static IP working now

Comment: my MAC change/static IP were working fine already, like i said in question. but thanks for your interest :)

Comment: I was unable to restart it by that command so I used GUI back then